# How to test a difference in proportions... over many iterations?

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion

I'd like to compare results between two set-ups (let's call them A & B) whose outputs are the proportions of a quantity allocated to three options let's call them (1,2 & 3). The null is that there is no difference in results when the inputs are process by set-up A and set-up B. Input data are randomly permutations of the same dataset, and given to each set-up, producing outputs in different proportions for each set-up, for each iteration. How would I test whether A & B are statistically different? Compute a chi-squared for each iteration and take the median?

In R:

```r
a <- matrix(rep(c(50,20),each=100) + runif(200)*15, ncol=2, 
            dimnames=list(paste("Iteration",1:100,sep="")))
a <- cbind(a, 100-apply(a,1,sum))
colnames(a) <- paste("A", 1:3, sep="")
head(a)

b <- matrix(rep(c(40,25), each=100) + runif(200)*15, ncol=2, 
            dimnames=list(paste("Iteration", 1:100,sep="")))
b <- cbind(b, 100-apply(b,1,sum))
colnames(b) <- paste("B", 1:3, sep="")
head(b)

boxplot(cbind(a,b), 
        main="H0: Proportions in A are no different from those in B", 
        xlab="A/B Models, 1/2/3 = components, 
              total=100% for each iteration")
```

Comment: In your setup (having to test a proportion), that is a special case of a mean, I would start by hypothesizing that for each outcome (1,2 or 3) I have a sum of Bernoulli random variables which make them a Binomial, then using local/global Moivre-Laplace theorem you could approximate it to a normal and then test it as usual...

Comment: Hi Delyan, thanks very much for posting.... that's a nice simple way of doing it, so thank you. I also discussed it with a colleague who suggested it could also be done by permutation testing by defining a quantity that suitably measures the discrepancy between the proportions, then comparing this between the observed data and permuted data. Another nice simple approach, which I just mention in case anyone comes across the same problem in the future! t